# Make autoscroll viewpager in reactnative

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make the sliding image. I have followed the [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager) . Its responding on sliding with fingers but not sliding automatically. How can I do so? I have implemented as follows:

```
<ViewPager style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0}>
                <View key="1">
                    <Image  style={ {height: '100%', width:'100%'}}source={{uri :'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441742917377-57f78ee0e582?h=1024'}}></Image>
                </View>
                <View key="2">
                <Image  style={ {height: '100%', width:'100%'}}source={{uri :'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441716844725-09cedc13a4e7?h=1024'}}></Image>
                </View>
</ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code I have found there is a method `setPage()` which accepts page number as argument.

Look at the example code they have provided where you can find how to use reference and call `setPage` method [Example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/master/example/ViewPagerExample.js#L98)

Now you can use `setInterval()` and make auto slide work.

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.viewPager.current.setPage(page);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I did not get  how  to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Set page is a method to update the page of the viewpager. You can autoscroll the viewpager using a timer and by updating the pager by using the setPage method. Below is the complete code for the same.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Platform } from 'react-native';

import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    pageNumber: 0,
    totalPage: 2
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var pageNumber = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.state.pageNumber >= 2) {
        pageNumber = 0;
      } else {
    pageNumber = this.state.pageNumber;
    pageNumber++;
  }
      console.log(pageNumber)
      this.setState({ pageNumber: pageNumber })
      this.viewPager.setPage(pageNumber)
    }, 2000);
  }
  render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ViewPager style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0}
      ref={(viewPager) => { this.viewPager = viewPager }}
      scrollEnabled={true}>
      <View key="1">
        <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>First page</Text>
      </View>
      <View key="2">
        <Text>Second page</Text>
      </View>

      <View key="3">
        <Text>Third page</Text>
      </View>
    </ViewPager>
  </View>
    );
      }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  viewPager: {
    flex: 1,
  },

});
```